# Powershell Most efficient way to combine customobject

Tags: powershell

I'm parsing a webpage, but having difficulty combining into one variable.
I'm looking for the most efficient way to do so as well.
This is code I have so far.  Any help is appreciated.

```
   $WebResponse = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://finviz.com/news.ashx"

$title = ($WebResponse.AllElements | Where {$_.class -match 'nn-tab-link'}).innertext
$time = ($WebResponse.AllElements | Where {$_.class -match 'nn-date'}).innertext
$link = ($WebResponse.AllElements | Where {$_.class -match 'nn-tab-link'}).href


$r =  {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        {Time(E/T)} = $time
        Headline = $title
        Link = $link
    }
}
 $R
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an index-based loop (which assumes that all three arrays have corresponding elements and the same element count):

```
$objects = foreach ($i in 0..($title.Count-1)) {
  [pscustomobject] @{
    'Time(E/T)' = $time[$i]
    Headline = $title[$i]
    Link = $link[$i]
  }
}
```

Note how property name `Time(E/T)` is enclosed in `'...'` - a verbatim string - rather than in `{...}` - a [*script block*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks); the latter only works *accidentally*, because script blocks stringify<sup>[1]</sup> to their verbatim content (without the `{` and `}`).

---

<sup>[1] When using the `[pscustomobject] @{ ... }` syntactic sugar, the keys of the hashtable (`@{ ... }`) are *implicitly stringified*, given that objects' property names are invariably strings.</sup>